failed virtualization attempt in windows bios
To be able to use Docker, I need to enable virtualization. When I activate it in the BIOS, the PC restarts and freezes on a black screen. I'm attaching a screenshot of my configuration. Apparently, my hardware is compatible for virtualization. Thanks for your help.
enter image description here
When I activate it in the BIOS, the PC restarts and freezes on a black screen.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

When I activate it in the BIOS  <- What or which BIOS setting did you change to activate  it?

I'm setting VS MODE to enable
